# Programmatically check whether a drive letter is a shared/network drive

Tags: python, winapi, network-drive, drive-letter

Is there a way to check whether a drive letter stands for a shared drive/network drive or a local disc in python? I guess there is some windows api function that gives me that info, but I can't find it. Perhaps there is even a method already integrated in python?

What I am looking for is something with this or similar behaviour:

```
someMagicMethod("C:\\")  #outputs True 'is a local drive'
someMagicMethod("Z:\\")  #outputs False 'is a shared drive'
```

That would help me as well:

```
someMagicMethod2()  #outputs list of shared drive letters
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `GetDriveType` function in `win32file` module may help you - it's a wrapper for the [GetDriveType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364939(VS.85).aspx) WINAPI function.

```
import win32file
isNetworkDrive = win32file.GetDriveType("Z:\\") == win32file.DRIVE_REMOTE
```

You'd be able to enumerate all with the `GetLogicalDriveStrings()` function in the `win32api` module, then use a loop to pick out only the network drives.

Comment: Great thats just what I was searching for! Thanks a lot!